# Flex DataGrid - how to find the maximum value in a column?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

How would I find the maximum value in a specific column in a Flex DataGrid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dataprovider of the datagrid can be arraycollection.  If you do the sorting of the arraycollection, then you will get maximum value in the first row.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a standard function/solution for this. 
A workaround could be to sort the column and get that result from which you can extract the highest value. Again, there doesn't seem to be a standard function for this.

More information about the sorting can be found [here](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Sorting_numeric_values_in_a_Flex_DataGrid-2881.html). 
Don't know if this was the answer you were hoping for, but I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I loop through my data to find the highest value.

I set the value of the 1st row to the specific column you are searching for.
Once set, I compare the next row to that value and reset the variable if
it's value is higher.

```
for (var y:int = 0; y < myData.length; y++)
{
    if(y == 0)    // initialize the first value
    {
        YourVariableHolder = myData.getItemAt(y).YourValue;     
    }

    // Compare the previous value to the current value in the loop
    if(myData.getItemAt(y).YourValue > YourVariableHolder)
    {
        YourVariableHolder = myData.getItemAt(y).YourValue;
    }
}
```